# jQuery global focus hook

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my focus manager I need to store some info on the last focus and blur. I need to delegate this hook to `body`, but if I use `*` as a filter I will receive the focus event for every parent item of the actual thing getting focus.

Realistically, I could make a filter to accept something like `a, input, button` ... etc, but also I need to refine it to `a:not([tabindex]=-1), *[tabindex!=-1]` etc.

But this gets complicated when one considers disabled controls. Is there a jQuery selector for `:focusable`, or how do I work around this? I could `debounce` my function, but even that is iffy.

EDIT:
Alright, my bad, I think what I am looking for here is `:tabbable`.

Comment: FYI, `:tabbable` isn't part of jQuery core but jQuery UI

Comment: You could select `*` and use `stopPropagation()` to prevent the event from bubbling, although this may cause unforeseen issues if you depend on the bubbling. Alternatively you could have a single event handler on the `document` and then inspect the `event.target` property.

Answer (score 0):

you can check focus by using: $("yourselector").is( ":focus" )

If you want to stop bubbling up to the dom just return false in your function after doing your stuff.`enter code here`